# Find the derivative of y with respect to t for y= ln(5t^3)

Tags: calculus

Would I use logarithmic notation here?

ln(y) = 3 * ln5t^2

= d/ds(ln y)= d/ds(3 * lnt^2)

Am I doing this right? I could be way off.

Comment: Are you trying to find $\frac{d}{dy} (\ln{y})$

Comment: i think so. I'm really confused as to where to start.

Comment: And, I'm guessing $ \ln(y) = 3\ln{(5t^2)} $?

Comment: Does $y=\ln(5t^3)$, or does $y=\ln(5t)^3$, or neither?

Comment: To reduce ambiguities, familiarize yourself with Mathjax, which is the pro equation writer. When asking a question, you'll see on the right a link to Mathkax help.

Answer (score 1):

Since $y=\ln(5t^3)=\ln5+\ln t^3=\ln5+3\ln t$,

$\displaystyle \;\;\;y^{\prime}=0+3\cdot\frac{1}{t}=\frac{3}{t}$.

Comment: $3\ln(5t^2)=\ln((5t^2)^3)\neq\ln(5t^3)$.

Comment: @ Sanath Devalapurkar I definitely agree with you; I am assuming the title of the problem is correct, but maybe it isn't.

Comment: I understand. Without latex, the problem is hard to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

If $y = 3\ln{(5t^2)}=\ln{(125t^6)}$ then, $y=\ln(125)+\ln(t^6)$ by the virtue of logarithms. Thus $$y'=\frac{d}{dt}(\ln(125)+\ln(t^6)) $$ $$=0+\frac{d}{dt}(6 \ln(t))$$ $$=6\cdot\frac{1}{t}$$ $$=\frac{6}{t}.$$

Comment: Ahh, I see that my answers is exactly the same as user84413, apart from the differing exponent.

Comment: @ MitchKnight I guess I'm not sure what the correct statement of the problem is; I was using the title as my source.

Comment: That's true. The method for solving the derivative has been shown though, so that should be sufficient.

Comment: There is a typo: it should be $ln(5t^2)^3=ln(5^3 t^6)$.

Comment: No issue. As $5^3$ still reduces to $0$ when taking the derivative. But thanks for noticing.

Comment: Sure! I just pointed it out in case our friend is not familiar with this property.

Comment: Yeah fair enough. Shows how important recognising little things like that are, it wasn't a typo I just wasn't thinking...